# Sorting Array while Skipping Value

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have this one-dimensional array:

`0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7, 4, 0`

I need to be able to sort this Array in C with a sorting algorithm more efficient than Bubble Sort, like Insertion Sort.  I also need to sort this in-place without creating a new array. However, I need to ignore the 0's.

An example sorted array would be:

`0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 7, 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run the same algorithm that you would run for insertion sort, except that when you actually shift the values, you skip the zeroes.

so take this example:

```
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7, 4, 0
```

Suppose there were no zeroes: `2, 1, 7, 4`.  You read the `1`, compare it to the previous value (2) and shift the 2 over into the spot that the `1` was in:

```
2, 1*, 7, 4 (copy 1 to register, shift the 2 since it is bigger than 1)
2, 2*, 7, 4 (write the 1 in that place)
1, 2*, 7, 4 (since there are no previous elements we are done)
```

And at the end of that iteration, everything before the asterisk is sorted.

The difference with the zeroes now is that you need to keep track of the "previous" and the "current" positions (`<` and `>`)

```
0, 0, 2, 0, 0<, 1*> (copy 1 to register, compare to value at `<`)
0, 0, 2, 0<, 0, 1*> (Since it is zero, move the previous head further back)
0, 0, 2<, 0, 0, 1*> (Since it is zero, move the previous head further back)
0, 0, 2<, 0, 0, 2*> (Check if 1 < 2.  Since it is, write the 2 in the current head)
0, 0, 2<>, 0, 0, 2*  (move the current head)
0, 0<, 2>, 0, 0, 2*  (move the previous head back)
0<, 0, 2>, 0, 0, 2*  (move the previous head back)
0<, 0, 1>, 0, 0, 2*  (Since we hit the front, we know that we have to write the `1` in the place marked by the "current" position)
```

For a case where you don't hit the end, consider `0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0`.  The steps in the sixth iteration are

```
0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2*<>, 0
....
0, 1<, 0, 3>, 0, 3*, 0 (do the comparison and see that 1 < 2 but 2 < 3, so we want to write the 2 here and end this iteration)

0, 1<, 0, 2>, 0, 3*, 0 (now we know the elements before the * are sorted, so we can move on)
```

Comment: You have helped me again.  You're the best.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Modify quick sort algorithm so that:

- When you decide whether an item goes left or right of the pivot it stays as is if 0
- Make sure you don't chose 0 as the pivot value. Hence, random qsort may be a better choice
- Make sure to return if the [recursive] input array is all zeros

For example, modified from [the Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#C):

```
void quick_sort (int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2) return;

    // don't sort all-zero sub-arrays:
    int c = 0,i;
    for (i=0; i < n; i++) { c += a[i]; }
    if (!c) return;

    // don't choose 0 as the pivot value:
    int p;
    do {
       p = a[rand()%n];
    } while (p == 0); 

    int *l = a;
    int *r = a + n - 1;

    // make sure not to move zeros:
    while (l[0] == 0 || l <= r) {
        if (*l < p) {
            l++;
            continue;
        }   
        if (r[0] == 0 || *r > p) {
            r--;
            continue; 
        }   
        int t = *l; 
        *l++ = *r; 
        *r-- = t;
    }   
    quick_sort(a, r - a + 1); 
    quick_sort(l, a + n - l); 
}
```

Comment: This is in C though, and Arrays aren't resizable like that.

Comment: You can do this by doing some extra copies

Comment: Sorry, I left that part out of my question.  Fixed in original question.

Answer (score -1):

First, start with the observation that when you limited your domain to integers, there is only one zero. The values that are to be ignored do not need to stay in memory. Otherwise, if you were sorting not integers, but pairs of integers ordered by the first coordinate, then there would be many zeroes ( `<0,0>`, `<0,1>`, ... ) and you would have to store them somehow.

In this case, you could move all the nonzero numbers to the beginning of the array, moving them to spots originally containing zeroes; while doing that, recording the indexes where the zeroes resided in the end of the array.

At this point, you could sort the beginning of the array and then interlace the values in order with zeroes, as you would have the appropriate indexes in the end of the array.